# How should you configure PowerShell logs permissions?

Tags: windows, forensics, hardening, powershell

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to configure Windows PowerShell logging, so that

1. it is secure (Attackers cannot gain sensitive data out of it)
2. it helps in DFIR (digital forensic and incident response) cases

The [CIS Benchmark for Windows 10](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/microsoft_windows_desktop/) (latest is v1.5.0 for release 1803) recommends to completely **disable** PowerShell logging due to the **bad default ACL** in Windows, which allows basically everyone to read the logs.

However because I know how valuable such a log can be in a DFIR case, I'd prefer to enable as much logging as possible but secure the access to the logs.

I found a good blog article on the MS technet which describes a way to configure the SDDL (security descriptor definition language):
[MS Technet Blog: Securing Your PS Operational Logs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kfalde/2017/05/13/securing-your-powershell-operational-logs/)

Does anyone have experience with PowerShell logging configurations regarding these aspects?

Comment: Hilariously, the CIS Benchmarks recommend disabling logging, but the CIS Top 20 recommend turning on logging.

Comment: I think this can be answered here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/180133/how-can-i-track-executed-powershell-commands-within-a-network

Comment: @Gaius No, it is not about how to enable logging in PowerShell, it is about how to properly secure the access to these logs by defining SDDLs etc...

Comment: @Adonalsium Exactly, they recommend disabling it because the default ACL is bad and allows everyone to read the potenitally sensitive content in those logs... That's why I'm trying to sitll enable them but protect them from unauthorized access